# 2-D vector Size

Tags: c++, vector, resize, 2d-vector

In C++ , I Made A Code That has A 2D Vector in it and Users are Required to give The inputs In 2D vector . I find It difficult To find The no. of rows in 2 vector with the help of size function.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int diagonalDifference(vector<vector<int>> arr)
{
    int d = arr[0].size();
    cout << d;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    vector<vector<int>> d;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        d[i].resize(size);
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            cin >> d[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << diagonalDifference(d);
}
```

The Output Should BE No. Rows , But it is coming NULL

Comment: Warning: Using `#include <vector>` along with `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` suggests you don't know what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does. Don't use stuff until you've researched and understood it. That said, once you've found out what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does and the implications, you'll probably not want to use it. But if you do continue to use it, be very careful using it in conjunction with `using namespace std;` because they make some of each other's worst effects much more likely to occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

> ```
> vector<vector<int>> d;
> for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
> {
>     d[i].resize(size);
>     //...
> ```

`d` is a vector of size `0` and accessing `d[i]` is out of bounds. You seem to be aware that you first have to resize the inner vectors, but you missed to do the same for the outer one. I dont really understand how your code can run as far as printing anything for `arr[0].size();` without segfaulting. Anyhow, the problem is that there is no element at `arr[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

But first, Look at your function argument -> is a copy of your vector ,use (vector<> & my vec) to avoid the copying mechanism of vector class (copy constructor for instance) cause if you put there your vector as a parameter and u will make some changes inside the function brackets you will not see any results ( if you dont wanna change your primary vector from function main, keep it without changes).

Secondly, look at code snippet pasted below.

```
std::vector<std::vector<typename>> my_vector{};
my_vector.resize(width);
for (size_t i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); ++i)
{
    my_vector[i].resize(height);
}
```

It gives you two dimensional vector

Operator[] for vector is overloaded and you have to use my_vector[0].size() just
my_vector[1].size() and so on ! I recommend for that displaying the size by kind of loops given in c++ standards

Regards!